# Problems with SSH ProxyCommand

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-keys, openssh

I have some problems with the ssh proxycommand. The authentication on the proxy works fine, but when i want to login to the remote-host it fails. The problem seems to be, that the proxy tries to login with my local rsa_key and not with the key stored on the proxy. Is there a way to fix this?

## This is what I want:

Local -- local rsa --> Proxy -- proxy rsa --> host

## The Config-file I use:

```
Host 192.168.178.32
HostName 192.168.178.32
User user
Port 22
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Host 192.168.178.30
HostName 192.168.178.30
User user
Port 22
IdentityFile home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p -F ssh_config -p 22 192.168.178
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748491/

Comment: Duplicate in this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295899/problems-with-ssh-proxycommand?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem seems to be, that the proxy tries to login with my local rsa_key and not with the key stored on the proxy.

Yes. It does. It is by design. You don't want to copy private keys over to the proxies. Proxy command will always authenticate from your local host.

There are twa ways out:

- Copy the key to your local host and configure it to be used.
- Don't use `ProxyCommand` and do the simple `ssh`:

  ```
  ssh -t proxy ssh host
  ```

  it will use the authentication from the second host

Comment: yeah i use the copy method now and it works well enough :) thanks