# SSH Jump Host WITHOUT Agent Forwarding

Tags: authentication, ssh, server, openssh, agent

Although a simple question, I have searched for days without success.

```
M = My machine 
J = Jump Host
S = Server

Jump Host has my public key on authorized_keys.
Server has J's public key on authorized_keys.

Allowed connections (due to key authentication):
M -> J
J -> S
```

How is it possible for me to ssh into S from my machine?

My current configuration is:

```
host jump
  user root
  HostName x.x.x.x

host server
  user root
  HostName x.x.x.x
  port 22
  ForwardAgent no
  ProxyCommand ssh jump -W %h:%p
```

It does not work as it tries to login with M's key.

Here's the ssh log

```
debug1: Host 'x.x.x.x' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/xxxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1542
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/xxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xxxxx/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xxxxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xxxxx/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
Killed by signal 1.
```

Comment: Newer versions of ssh have a `ProxyJump` option which is more direct than the `ProxyCommand`. But at the end it should work exactly the same.

Comment: Side note: This means that you have got your private and public key on jump server (shared-server) which doesn't sound very secure.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382659/

Comment: Cross-post: https://serverfault.com/questions/827361

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Of course it tries to login with M's key. You are not really connecting from J to S.

The first ssh connection is from M to J. This one simply sets up some forwarding. The second ssh connection is directly from M to S using the forwarding set up by the first ssh. - No chance to use the key on J.

You might use `ssh -A jump ssh-add` to add J's key to your agent.
Then your setup should work fine.

Another idea might be something like `ssh -t jump ssh server`. This way you log into J and from there you log into S, pretty much as you expected it.

Comment: Exactly. I've give it more of a read and you are correct.
I was trying to avoid the agent forwarding as that's bad practice and currently insecure.
Same with 'ssh -t jump ssh server' as that runs another ssh process in the jump server and if attackers have access to the machine they can compromise the ssh binary and still gain access.
Thank you! I'll stick with keeping they keys on my host for now and using ProxyCommand :)